# Make horizontal DIV to vertical DIV (css)

Tags: html, css

I would like to get the example (hearts) at the bottom of the page in vertical order instead the horizontal order. I tried a lot, but I cannot get it working. Does anybody can help out here?

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?m_Wywb1B

Comment: add your code / fiddle

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will at least get you started...

```
span {
 display: block;
}
```

Then remove the `overflow: hidden` from the parent div's.